# How do I load a UI file from a postgres database in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, style

I have a custom form I made and associated python code I made. Right now both are stored on mapped network drive and the layer style that gets saved to postgres references the .ui and .py file on the network drive.

Ideally, I would like it all to load as part of the style saved in the database. I was able to save the python code as part of the style by saving it in the "Provide code in this dialog" option but I cannot get a UI to load from the database.

When saving the style to the database, I did check the save UI to database and pointed it to the right file to load. But when I load the style, it still points to the same place on the network drive in the "Edit UI" input box.

I have tried various combinations like leaving it to auto-generate and whatnot but it doesn't seem to ever pull the form from the database no matter what I do.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: I do not think it is possible out of the box. The saved styles is a fuzzy subset of the layer properties, where you have to test whats get saved. You will have to code the missing parts yourself.

Comment: Has this changed at all in the 4 years or so since this comment was added? I am wondering if there is anything that has been developed since that might overcome this? Although posing this question from a position of ignorance as I don't know if this is something that can be solved 'out of the box'? Or if not, how does one go about coding this to work?